# Can we use Cordova-Bluetooth-Printer-Plugin in SAP fiori client App without Hybrid App?

Tags: cordova, printing, bluetooth, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am Developing SAPUI5 Fiori Apps.
My App Having Print option and I am using Bluetooth Printer EPSON EPOS P60II.
The print should work via Bluetooth.

I have seen some of the blogs related this

- [Bluetooth Printer Integration with SAPUI5 Mobile Application](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3743712#)
- [UI5 App With Cordova Plugins](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/01/30/creating-a-ui5-app-and-integrating-with-cordova-plugins-part-1/)

But by looking into these blogs I understand that we need to Develop Hybrid  Apps.

1. Is Hybrid  will work within SAP Fiori Client?
2. Is Cordova plugin will work by default in SAP Fiori Client?

Answer (score 0):

For SAP Fiori Client cordova plugins read: [Kapsel and Cordova Plugins for SAP Fiori Client](https://help.sap.com/doc/38ec5403bfbf4d7a8fdd3fee5f9605e0/3.0.14/en-US/dd84adc65a5e4a2490e52d2394b7d954.html).
Then you can use [Cordova-Plugin-Bluetooth-Printer](https://github.com/srehanuddin/Cordova-Plugin-Bluetooth-Printer) for printing.

Comment: SAP Fiori Client Supported printer plugin is not providing Bluetooth Connectivity(https://help.sap.com/doc/38ec5403bfbf4d7a8fdd3fee5f9605e0/3.0.14/en-US/dd84adc65a5e4a2490e52d2394b7d954.html). and as you mentioned https://github.com/srehanuddin/Cordova-Plugin-Bluetooth-Printer this is the android Plugin.How it will work in Fiori Client?

Comment: @SrinivasGadilli, it will require JavaScript glue code to get the plugin to work with the cordova Fiori Client.